# Java for every 6 remove 1

Tags: java

I'm making a system.
What I want is, for every 6 items you have to buy 5 (so when the price is 5 each item, 6 items is not 30 but 25, same with 12, 18, 24 etc...)

How would I do that?

I thought it would be something like this:

`if (amount % 6 == 0) {`

```
    }</code>
```

But that would get it one time if I'm correct.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Comment: Even if you have not tried writing any code yet, at least try to formulate your task in a way that others (who never heard about it) could possibly guess what's it all about.

Comment: How would you work it out yourself on a piece of paper? Think about this and then write some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulus operator won't work in this situation.
So for an efficient solution.

```
int numberOfItems = 17; //however many there are
int discount = numberOfItems / 6;

double priceToPay = price * (numOfItems - discount);
```

By having the discount as an `int` you won't get any rounding or decimal part after the division.

Comment: True, yours is more efficient. I didn't think of just cutting off the decimal part, my solution is pretty much manual division.

Comment: @Jaybob may as well take advantage of the inbuilt `/` division operator :)

Answer (score 0):

Using modulus will only give you the discount if you have 6, 12, etc. items. What about if you have 7 items? You won't get any discount (it is not divisible by 6)! So, it would be something like this:

```
    int numOfItems = 6; //this will be different every time
    //copy numOfItems because it will be modified
    int temp = numOfItems;

    double price = 5;
    int discount = 0;

    //While there are at least 6 items
    while (temp >= 6) {
        discount++; //discount one item
        temp -= 6; //take away 6
    }

    //you have to pay for the number of items, but not the discounted items
    double amountToPay = price * (numOfItems - discount);
```

This way, every time you take away 6, you don't have to pay for 1 item.

Comment: this isn't a very efficient solution.